# Send e-mail from VB 2012

Tags: vb.net

I would like to send a message from my form, but Im receiving the following error:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. 
The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. mw4sm56776703wic.20 - gsmtp
```

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim email As New MailMessage
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
    email.From = New MailAddress("my gmail account")
    email.Subject = "Hello!"
    email.To.Add("the one I want to send it to")
    smtp.Port = 25    'i use an aruba email, it work with other application'
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("the gmail account i used", "pwd i have hided it")
    smtp.Send(email)
End Sub
```

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may need to enable a secure connection:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim email As New MailMessage
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
    email.From = New MailAddress("my gmail account")
    email.Subject = "Hello!"
    email.To.Add("the one I want to send it to")
    smtp.Port = 465 ' From Joel's answer, encryption requires port 465 rather than 25
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("the gmail account i used", "pwd i have hided it")
    smtp.EnableSsl = True ' *** Add this line ***
    smtp.Send(email)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: @Hfirst: see my edited answer or Joel Coehoorn's answer regarding the port number.

Answer (score 2):

You mention a gmail account and the gmail smtp server. Gmail does not allow unencrypted smtp access, which is what port 25 is for. You need to use port 465, and tell .Net to do the correct encryption:

```
smtp.Port = 465
smtp.EnableSSL = True
```